# Azure Data Explorer streaming ingestion metrics are empty

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-data-explorer

I have enabled streaming ingestion on my ADX cluster and data is ingested without any issue from an IoTHub. However the streaming ingestion metrics give me no results. Any clues?

[image: Streaming ingestion]

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell with no details about your cluster. Please open a support ticket via the Azure portal with the details of your ADX cluster and the database/tables used for streaming ingestion.

Comment: Did you also enable streaming ingestion on the table itself or only on the cluster?

Comment: Yes @Avnera. Streaming works like a charm, just no metrics :)